# How do I increase the spacing between subplots with subplot2grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use `subplot2grid` to make a subplot like the following:

[image]

In order to make the ticks sufficiently large for publication, I need to increase the vertical and horizontal spacing between axes.

Normally, I would use something like `subplot_adjust(hspace = 0.5)`, but that doesn't seem to work with `subplot2grid`.

Could anyone please recommend a solution?

Here is the code I use to plot things and create the axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1  = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(0,0), colspan = 2)
ax2  = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(1,0), colspan = 1)
ax3  = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(1,1), colspan = 1)

df.plot( ax = ax1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might want to post the code you used to generate the subplots.

Comment: Posted some of the code.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout)

The code is as follows:

```
AX = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
AX.update(wspace = 0.5, hspace = 0.5)
ax1  = plt.subplot(AX[0,:])
ax2 = plt.subplot(AX[1,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(AX[1,1])
```

Which produces the same subplots with increased horizontal and vertical spacing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. Because I have a twin y-axis on the left column, the labels still overlap with those on the right column, even if I set `hspace=0.8`

Comment: update myself: I found that adding an extra `figure.tight_layout()` got it right.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following line:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.8)
```

under this one:

```
ax3 =plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(1,1), colspan = 1)
```

You can play with all sorts of parameters this way.